# Angular routing is not working with express

Tags: angularjs, express

I am doing a sample MEAN application.I have my angular routing but when I am making any request it is directly hitting the server and giving me a Cannot GET /movies.

Here below is my server side code for serving static files.

```
 //Serve html files
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

//Register all the client folder
var client = __dirname + '/modules';
fs.readdir(client, function(err,files) {
    files.map(function(file){
        app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/modules'+'/'+file+'/client')));
    })
});

//Serve js files
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/public')));

//Load the models
app.models = require('./index');

//Load the routes
var routes = require('./routes');
_.each(routes,function(controller,route){
    app.use(route,controller(app,route));
});
```

Inside my client folder another folder called 'view' is there where all my templates are there.

Below is my routing for /movie URL

```
angular.module('movies').config(['$stateProvider',
  function ($stateProvider) {
    // Movies state routing
    $stateProvider
      .state('movies.list', {
        url: '/movies',
        templateUrl: 'views/movie.html'
      })
    }
]);
```

Comment: Update the question with latest code

Comment: Are  you jusing ui-router ? http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router

Comment: Yes Venkat I am using ui-router.

Comment: Just for testing in my HTML"<a href="movie">Movie</a>" is there.When the URL changes to localhost://3000/Movie I am getting Cannot GET /movies even if it is configured in routing.

Answer (score 0):

Add `urlRouterProvider` to config and Add Controller to `stateProvider.state`:

```
myApp.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
  //
  // For any unmatched url, redirect to /state1
  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/state1");
  //
  // Now set up the states
  $stateProvider
    .state('state1.list', {
      url: "/list",
      templateUrl: "partials/state1.list.html",
      controller: function($scope) {
        $scope.items = ["A", "List", "Of", "Items"];
      }
    })
});
```

Reference:
https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router

Comment: That one I have added.Still the same error.My angular routing is not at all triggering.

Comment: Just for testing in my HTML"<a href="movie">Movie</a>" is there.When the URL changes to localhost://3000/Movie I am getting Cannot GET /movies even if it is configured in routing.

Answer (score 0):

By using the dot in your state name `.state('movies.list', {` you are creating a nested state 'list' of the parent state 'movies'.

If you do not wish to create a nested state, remove the dot and name it something like 'listMovies', and it should work.

**Update**

in your express configuration:

```
app.get('/*', function(req, res) { 
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html')
});
```

and in your angular route:

```
angular.module('movies').config(['$stateProvider', '$locationProvider',
  function ($stateProvider, $locationProvider) {
    // Movies state routing
    $stateProvider
      .state('movies', {
        url: '/movies',
        templateUrl: 'views/movie.html'
      });
     $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
    }
]);
```

Comment: just to clarify, are you calling localhost:PORT/#/movies?

Comment: No to avoid those hash prefixes I have enabled HTML5 mode.my request is going as http://localhost:3000/movies.I am wondering why angular side routing is not happening.

Comment: Hi after adding these lines because of app.get(/*) I am now getting 'Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <' error.

Comment: could you paste the updated code here? and did you use `app.get(/*)` or `app.get('/*')`?